# How can I convert this remap to a <expr>?

Tags: vimscript

N.B. my question title might be poor, so feel free to improve it.

### Background

I want to write a command to move my cursor to the body of my email, add blank lines, and change to insert mode. Previously, I used the following for **new emails**.

```
nnoremap gb <C-Home>/^$<CR>:nohlsearch<CR>o
```

`mutt` would create a new email in `vim`, then I'd press `gb`. The cursor would move to the top of the email (`<C-Home>`), find the first blank line and immediately stop highlighting (`/^$<CR>:nohlsearch<CR>`), create a new line and start editing a new line (`o`).

However, I often **reply to an email**, and I wanted to automatically create another "buffer" empty line below my cursor position. Hence, I changed the command to this following.

```
nnoremap gb <C-Home>/^$<CR>:nohlsearch<CR>o<Esc>ko
```

This would do as above, then get into normal mode `<Esc>`, move up (`k`), and create another new line to edit `o`.

### Conditional

I wanted to create a conditional. After searching for the first blank line (`<C-Home>/^$<CR>:nohlsearch<CR>`), if this were the last line of the email, I'd be editing a new email, so just `o`. Otherwise, I'd be replying, so `o<Esc>ko`. The following doesn't work, because I've mangled together different syntaxes, but it should give an idea of what I want.

```
nnoremap gb <C-Home>/^$<CR>:nohlsearch<CR>|if line('.') != line('$')|o<Esc>k|endif|o
```

I suspect `nnoremap <expr> gb ...` is useful, but I'm not sure how to use it.

Comment: You may want to create a function for this and call it with `nnoremap gb :call YourFunction()<CR>`. In the function you can do all your mapping is currently doing and have a more nicer view.

Comment: @Nobe4 I think part of my problem is confusion between `remap`, `remap <expr>`, `function` and `command`. I'm not sure what I'm writing where. I'm not sure exactly what syntax to use for this function, as obviously my last piece of code is a hybrid of different things (and doesn't work as is). Could you possibly write an answer with the function code itself?

Comment: Done, check my answer and ask if you have any question

Comment: @Sparhawk: As a general heads up in vimscript a command is an operation that you start from the command mode which you enter with `:` (example `:echo "foo"`). A function is a set of commands that you define in your `.vimrc` or another `.vim` file, you can call the function from the command line mode `:call YourFunction()`. Finally a mapping is the fact to assign an action to a key or a key sequence (e.g. `:map <C-a> :call YourFunction()<CR>` says to Vim "When I press Ctrl-a do as if I had press `:` followed by `call YourFunction` followed by `Enter`).

Comment: @statox Thank you very much for that. That makes it a bit clearer. So you can `map` keystrokes like `gg`, but if you wanted to move to the top of a file with a function or command, you couldn't use that keystroke. The other thing that got me was that you couldn't use `normal!` in a command, but apparently it's okay in a function.

Comment: @Sparhawk: `gg` is a normal mode mapping so if you want to use it in a function you have to say to vim "Use gg as if I was in normal mode" you do that with `normal gg`. In the command line using `:normal gg` will be the same as typing `gg` in normal mode. Actually the best I can advise to you is to [learnVimScriptTheHardWay](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/) it might be a lot of reading but you'll find an answer to 98% of your questions there and you can ask the 2% remaining on this site ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There you go, I'm not sure to have understood perfectly your use case, bu you can add your workflow to this example :

```
function! Mail()
  normal! gg
  call search('^$')
  nohlsearch
  if line('.') != line('$')
    normal! o
    normal! k
  endif
  normal! o
  startinsert
endfunction

nnoremap gb :call Mail()<CR>
```

Note that you can execute `normal!` to prevent mapping to be used.

Comment: Oh, one small problem. It doesn't leave me in insert mode at the end. I can just append `i` to `nnoremap gb ...`, but is there a more elegant way (by modifying the function instead)?

Comment: Yes, let me update my answer